# Python: Selenium find element by xpath returns empty list

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the values of open, high, low, close of the interactive chart on this website: [Currency Chart from website](https://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd-chart).

This is the xpath of the element: `//*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1]`

I have added an attribute `name` on html debugger, tried to `find_elements_by_name` but it also returned an empty list. The `find_by_class_name` method returns error that cannot search compound values. I need to get the Open, High, Low and Close values whenever I hover the mouse on the chart and print it in the console.

I am trying to get the value at the same time I move the mouse on the chart area. I don't know if it is because the field is dynamic, as it changes as I scroll on the chart.

Edit: The values are located at the top left corner of the chart and when you move the mouse in the chart area, the cursor snaps to the point and the data gets updated. Even in the raw version of the data, [Raw Data Website](http://tvc4.forexpros.com/aeb8b23f0074442fbcea40e8a863a9ec/1496785051/1/1/8/history?symbol=1&resolution=1&from=1396699446&to=1496785906), I cannot get the content of the elements when using `class names="line-content"`, `css_selector = 'html body'` or the `xpath='/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]'`.

The outputs are like this: `Message: Unable to locate element: .line-content`, `Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]`

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd-chart")
open_value_1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1]')

# If mouse moved and the value changed - print it
while True:
    open_value_2 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1]')
    if open_value_2 is not open_value_1:
        print(open_value_2)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: the elements on that site have proper IDs, so why on Earth are you not using them, and instead putting this crazy xpath with indexes? how do you know that it's even correct?

Comment: And why do you have absolute xpath in your code ? Even if your xpath is correct, it will fail when the dom under cosideration changes. Also, please point us to the high, low etc in the webpage.

Comment: @KirilS. I didn't find any ID, please tell me where to look for them so I can change the script accordingly to make it work.

Comment: @testerjoe2 I edited my post, I found the raw data website the gives the data to the chart, but cannot find elements by class_name, css path or xpath.

Comment: as far as I can see element `@id="chart-area"` is located on 4th level of iframe which means you need to switch into every frame.

Comment: @KirilS. I have searched for the frame `chart-area` and selenium finds it but fails to find the subframe. Code: `browser.switch_to.frame(0) or browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('chart-area')` and after: `browser.find_element_by_class_name('pane-legend-item-value-title pane-legend-line')`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is some issue with your Xpath

```
(//*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1])
```

you can try bellow Xpath

```
//*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]
```

Comment: or this one //*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]//span[@class="pane-legend-item-value pane-legend-line main"]

Comment: This xpath also returns error `is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`. As explained by @KirilS., it may be because of the multiple frames on the website.

Comment: For me Xpath is  working @VascoFerreira  //*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]/span[@class="pane-legend-item-value-title pane-legend-line"]

Comment: I have used this code: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chart-area"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div‌​/div[3]/div[1]/div/s‌​pan[1]/span[@class="‌​pane-legend-item-val‌​ue-title pane-legend-line"]'` and it returned: `Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression`